# childWindow control in silverlight as a custom control

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight

i know that silverlight already has a child window control , but i want to use this child window control from my own library.

specifically i want the code to look something like this:
XAML:

```
<mycontrols:myChildWindow x:Class="SilverlightClassLibrary1.ChildWindow1"
       xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
       xmlns:mycontrols="clr-namespace:mynamespace;assembly=myassembley"
       Width="400" Height="300" 
       Title="ChildWindow1">
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Margin="2">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Button x:Name="CancelButton" Content="Cancel" Click="CancelButton_Click" Width="75" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,12,0,0" Grid.Row="1" />
    <Button x:Name="OKButton" Content="OK" Click="OKButton_Click" Width="75" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,12,79,0" Grid.Row="1" />
</Grid>
```

and my project would reference myassembly.dll , which would have mynamespace in it.And there would be class myChildWindow in mynamespace.This class can inherit from System.windows.control.childwindow (possibly).

I know this is a weird implementation way.But i need it to be like this. please tell me how would i implement myChildWindow class?

If the question is not clear ,please ask further questions.i can make the edits in the question.

Comment: The code you provided should be fine, except `<mycontrols:myChildWindow` should be `<controls:myChildWindow` to match the namespace you included.

Comment: yes sir. But my question is how would i implement myChildWindow ?

Comment: `public class myChildWindow : ChildWindow { public myChildWindow() : base(){} }` should be enough to work.

Comment: yeah .but this is just the c# code. what would be the xaml code for myChildWindow . Coz i already tried this way ,and gives me error in xaml file where i use myChildWindow

Answer (score 1):

You need 2 things.

**1. Create class derived from ChildWindow**

```
namespace mynamespace
{    
    public class myChildWindow : ChildWindow
    {
        public myChildWindow():base()
        {
            //Add custom constructor code
        }
    }
}
```

**2. In XAML change**

> xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"

to

> xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/client/2007"

Look at example with XAML body:

```
<mycontrols:myChildWindow x:Class="Project.Views.EditReport"
           xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/client/2007"
           xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
           xmlns:mycontrols="clr-namespace:mynamespace;assembly=myassembley"
           Width="400"
           Title="Edit Report"></CWindow>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me as though you have already answered your own question. As mentioned above, you can inherit from ChildWindow. But, after that, what you need to do is include a reference to the assembly with this class in it in your Silverlight project. Once you do that, the assembly will be added to the AppManifest, the DLL will be included in the Xap package, and you will be able to reference it in Xaml as you already have done.

The namespace above is incorrect thought. It should be:

```
namespace mynamespace
{    
    public class myChildWindow : ChildWindow
    {
        public myChildWindow():base()
        {
            //Add custom constructor code
        }
    }
}
```

It should be compiled in to the assembly named "myassembley". However, you can't use x:Class in your Xaml if you are referencing another assembly.